# get path from an image on linux with Java

Tags: java, linux, path

Environment of work:
windows 7, 
fedora 20,
Java 7_79,
maven,
eclipse

**EDIT**

I have a web java project with maven and  I'm trying to get an image that i have in src/main/resouces package to put the image on an email, this image later is set into the war at folder WEB-INF/classes/html. when run the project at  windows 7 everything works fine but the problem is when i run my web project on fedora 20 (linux) i get the next error:

```
> 21:26:09,662 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-92) java.lang.NullPointerException
> 21:26:09,662 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-92)   at
> javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:226)
> 21:26:09,663 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-92)   at
> javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:299)
> 21:26:09,663 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-92)   at
> javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1375)
> 21:26:09,663 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-92)   at
> javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1021)
> 21:26:09,664 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-92)   at
> javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:419)
> 21:26:09,664 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-92)   at
> javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1354)
> 21:26:09,664 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-92)   at
> javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2107)
> 21:26:09,665 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-92)   at
> javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2075)
> 21:26:09,665 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-92)   at
> javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:123) 21:26:09,666 ERROR
> [stderr] (Thread-92)  at
> com.acertum.serc.util.SolicitudEmail.enviarCorreo(SolicitudEmail.java:148)
> 21:26:09,666 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-92)   at
> com.acertum.serc.controller.AgregarExcepcionView$1.run(AgregarExcepcionView.java:383)
```

this is the method that obtains the image's  path

```
public MimeBodyPart obtenerImagen(String urlImagen) throws IOException, MessagingException{
    logger.info("entro");
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(urlImagen);
    logger.info("url" + url);
    MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    logger.info("url.getPath()" + url.getPath().toString());
    attachmentPart.attachFile(url.getPath());
    attachmentPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
    return attachmentPart;
}
```

my principal method to send the email is the next:

```
try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(ScoreConstants.getFromSolicitudEmail()));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipientes);
            message.setSubject(ScoreConstants.getSubjectSolicitudEmail());
            String fechaSistema="<html><body><br/><br/><br/><div align='right'><h3>M&eacute;xico,D.F a "+date+"</h3></div><br/>";
            String  nombreAcreditado="<br/><br/><div style='font-family: Calibri;'><strong>Acreditado: </strong> "+ acreditado +"</div><br/>";
            String  tipoproducto="<div style='font-family: Calibri;'><strong>Tipo de Producto: </strong>"+ subproducto +"</div><br/>";
            String  numeroMonto="<div style='font-family: Calibri;'><strong>Monto: </strong>"+ monto +"</div><br/>";
            String  descripcionExcepcion="<div style='font-family: Calibri;'><strong>Descripcion de la excepci&oacute;n: </strong>"+ descripcion +"</div><br/>";



            String linkAceptada = "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><div style='margin-left: 350px;font-family: Calibri;'><a href='http://"+ ScoreConstants.getIpServidorWeb()+":"+ScoreConstants.getPuertoServidorWeb()+"/ScoreExcepciones/AceptadoRechazado.xhtml?nombre="
                    + acreditado
                    + "&celular="
                    + celular
                    + "&fase="
                    + fase
                    + "&excepcionId="
                    + excepcionId
                    + "&subproductoId="
                    + subproductoId
                    + "&version="
                    + version
                    + "&empleadoId="
                    + empleadoId
                    + "&ipAddres="
                    + ipAddress
                    + "&accion="+autorizar+"'>Autorizar</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                    + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='http://"+ScoreConstants.getIpServidorWeb()+":"+ScoreConstants.getPuertoServidorWeb()+"/ScoreExcepciones/AceptadoRechazado.xhtml?nombre="
                    + acreditado
                    + "&celular="
                    + celular
                    + "&fase="
                    + fase
                    + "&excepcionId="
                    + excepcionId
                    + "&subproductoId="
                    + subproductoId
                    + "&version="
                    + version
                    + "&empleadoId="
                    + empleadoId
                    + "&ipAddres="
                    + ipAddress
                    + "&accion="
                    + rechazar+ "'>Rechazar</a></div>";
            String cadena = String.format("%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", fechaSistema,
                    obtenerRutaContenido(File.separator + "html" + File.separator + "Correo.html"),
                    nombreAcreditado, tipoproducto, numeroMonto,
                    descripcionExcepcion, linkAceptada);






            MimeBodyPart cadenaContenido = new MimeBodyPart();
            cadenaContenido.setContent(cadena, "text/html");
            String rutaPiePagina=obtenerRutaContenido((File.separator  +"html" + File.separator + "PiePagina.html"));


            MimeBodyPart piePagina = new MimeBodyPart();
            piePagina.setContent(rutaPiePagina, "text/html");


            MimeBodyPart imagenCreada=obtenerImagen(("html" + File.separator + "Logo-AcertumBank-S.jpg"));

            message.setContent(ordenContenidos(imagenCreada,cadenaContenido,piePagina));

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
            e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
            e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
obtenerRutaContenido(File.separator + "html" + File.separator + "Correo.html"),
...
obtenerRutaContenido((File.separator  +"html" + File.separator + "PiePagina.html"));
...
obtenerImagen(("html" + File.separator + "Logo-AcertumBank-S.jpg"));
```

If `obtenerRutaContenido()` and `obtenerImagen()` are similar you would need to start path with `File.separator` too.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily you do *not* have a File (on the file system) but a resource (in a jar/war/class path/...).

```
public MimeBodyPart obtenerImagen(String urlImagen) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    logger.info("entro");
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(urlImagen);
    MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart(url.openStream());
    attachmentPart.setFileName(url.getFile()); // Just "xyz.jpg" maybe
    attachmentPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
    //attachmentPart.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    return attachmentPart;
}
```

This takes the InputStream of the resource to the MimeBodyPart constructor to fill the contents of it.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer but this not fix the problem, i tried it but  the error that appears is the same

Comment: On Windows file system path names are case-insensitive, elsewhere not. And a path with ClassLoader must be something absolute like "def/klm/xyz.png", without starting slash. (Changed setFile into setFileName too.)

Comment: hi, i implemented your advices and seem work fine thanks but your solution sends the image on base64, is possible send the image  in the jpg format and not in base 64 on linux? because in windows7 my code works fine

Comment: Added a `setContentType` to the part.

Comment: I can't put the method setContentType(image/jpeg) because attachmentPart dont have that method, I put the sentence  attachmentPart.setContent(url.getFile(), "image/jpeg") but now in the mail the  image appears as follows:

 ÿØÿàJFIFddÿìDucky<ÿî&AdobedÀ
Content-Disposition: inline; 
   filename="/content/ScoreExcepciones.war/WEB-INF/classes/html/Logo-AcertumBank-S.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: image/jpeg; 
   name="/content/ScoreExcepciones.war/WEB-INF/classes/html/Logo-AcertumBank-S.jpg"

/content/ScoreExcepciones.war/WEB-INF/classes/html/Logo-AcertumBank-S.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I am momentary not at a Java project.with mail. Maybe comment out setDisposition. Remove the "answered" check mark.